# Using regex to create new column in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and in one of its columns i need to pull out specific text and place it into its own column. From the dataframe below i need to take elements of the LAUNCH column and add that into its own column next to it, specifically i need to extract the date in the rows which provide it, for example 'Mar-24'.

df =

```
 |LAUNCH               
0|Step-up Mar-24:x1.5    
1|unknown                 
2|NTV:62.1%               
3|Step-up Aug-23:N/A,
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

df =

```
 |LAUNCH               |DATE 
0|Step-up Mar-24:x1.5  | Mar-24 
1|unknown              | nan  
2|NTV:62.1%            | nan  
3|Step-up Aug-23:N/A,  | Aug-23
```

And if this can be done, would it also be possible to display the date as something like 24-03-01 (yyyy-mm-dd) rather than Mar-24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `str.extract`, looking for any match on day of the month:

```
months = (pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([*range(1,12)]), format='%m')
          .dt.month_name()
          .str[:3]
          .values.tolist())

pat = rf"((?:{'|'.join(months)})-\d+)"
# '((?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov)-\\d+)'

df['DATE '] = df.LAUNCH.str.extract(pat)
```

---

```
print(df)

         LAUNCH          DATE 
0  Step-up Mar-24:x1.5  Mar-24
1              unknown     NaN
2            NTV:62.1%     NaN
3   Step-up Aug-23:N/A  Aug-23
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *str.extract* with a named capturing group.
The code to add a new column with the extracting result can be e.g.:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.LAUNCH.str.extract(
    r'(?P<DATE>(?:Jan|Feb|Ma[ry]|Apr|Ju[nl]|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{2})')], 
    axis=1, sort=False)
```

The result, for your data, is:

```
                LAUNCH    DATE
0  Step-up Mar-24:x1.5  Mar-24
1              unknown     NaN
2            NTV:62.1%     NaN
3  Step-up Aug-23:N/A,  Aug-23
```